# Unable to access values in VueJS template

Tags: vue.js

I can't access the user's email in my template. Here's what I did:

```
Vue.component('officemates', {
    props: ['officemate'],
    template: '<li>{{ officemate.name }} | <a href="{{ officemate.website }}">{{ officemate.website }}</a></li>'
});

var officemates = new Vue({
    el: '#my-officemates',
    data: {
        myOfficeMates: [
            { name: 'Jolo Pedrocillo', website: 'https://www.oneman.com/' },
            { name: 'Lucel Del Campo', website: 'https://www.single-mom.com/' },
            { name: 'PJ Manahon', website: 'https://www.thebigone.com' },
            { name: 'Evan Ortega', website: 'https://www.goodguy.com' }
        ]
    }
})
```

When I check the rendered page I can see the list but the link is like this:

```
http://localhost/dev_beta/vue/{{ officemate.website }}
```

I am still studying VueJS for my next project. I hope you can help me with my simple problem.

I am using version Vue.js v2.1.10

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) for this:

```
<a v-bind:href="officemate.website">{{ officemate.website }}</a>
```

or in short you can also do:

```
<a :href="officemate.website">{{ officemate.website }}</a>
```

Comment: Ok now it's working. Can you explain to me why in the `:href="myurl"` the `{{ }}` is not needed?

Comment: @Jerielle With v-bind you can dynamically bind one or more attributes to vue data variables. see similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41210338/1610034).